# Web API Get Raw Value from [ValidationAttribute]

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, json.net, data-annotations, model-binding

hi I have this custom validation attribute:

```
public sealed class TestValidation : ValidationAttribute
{
    public TestValidation ()
    {
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
public class Test 
{
    [TestValidation]
    public DateTime? DateUpdated { get; set;}
}
```

I have JSON value like this:

```
{ "DateUpdated": "abcdefg" }
```

What happen is, since "abcdefg" is not a valid DateTime format, it automatically converts it to null since the destination data type is Nullable. Is it possible to get the raw value (abcdefg) on the TestValidation class?

Comment: There are multiple ways to do this.
Please have a look on this post:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rahul4_saxena/mvc-4-custom-validation-data-annotation-attribute/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override the IsValid method.

Here is what you should do to make it done.

```
public sealed class TestValidation : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)  
    {
        //value contains the value of datetime 'DateUpdated' (abcdefg)
    }
}
```